# Golang mux http.FileServer not returning image

Tags: http, go

I am new to go and am trying to setup a go server. My intention is to return an image when the url is hit.

this is what i have done

```
myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
myRouter.HandleFunc("/poster_path/{id}",posterfunc)
```

This is my posterfunc

```
func posterfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["id"]
    var url = "/home/rakshithjk/Desktop/poster/"+key+".jpg"
    http.FileServer(http.Dir(url))
}
```

This is the output in Postman -
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE - 
tried changing `http.FileServer` to `http.ServeFile`, but the output remains the same
Modified handler function

```
func posterfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["id"]
    var url = "/home/rakshithjk/Desktop/poster/"+key+".jpg"
    http.ServeFile(w, r,url)
```

This is my entire file contents(for reference)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "encoding/json"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    //"github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
)


func handleRequests() {
    myRouter := mux.NewRouter()
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/movie/top_rated", returnSingleArticle)
    myRouter.HandleFunc("/poster_path",posterfunc)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":10000", myRouter))
}

func enableCors(w *http.ResponseWriter) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")

}
type movie_list struct {
    Page int `json:"page"`
    Results []movie `json:"results"`
}
type movie struct {
    Id      int `json:"id"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    Language    string `json:"language"`
    Release_date string `json:"release_date"`
    Poster_path string `json:"poster_path"`
    Background_path string `json:"background_path"`
    Overview string `json:"overview"`
    Genre_ids string `json:"genre_ids"`
}

func posterfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    //vars := mux.Vars(r)
    //key := vars["id"]
    enableCors(&w)

    var url = "/home/rakshithjk/go/src/clumio/112.png"
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q\n", url)
    http.ServeFile(w, r,url)
}

func homePage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Welcome to the HomePage!")
    fmt.Println("Endpoint Hit: homePage")
}

func returnSingleArticle(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //vars := mux.Vars(r)
    //key := vars["id"]
    enableCors(&w)
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "root:72574484@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)/PicturePerfect")
             if err != nil {
                 fmt.Println(err)
                 }else{
                 fmt.Println("Connection Established")
             }
    rows,err:=db.Query("select * from movies limit 10")

         if err!=nil{
            fmt.Println(err)
         }

         var list movie_list
         var tag movie

         for rows.Next(){

             err:=rows.Scan(&tag.Id,&tag.Title,&tag.Language,&tag.Release_date,&tag.Poster_path,&tag.Background_path,&tag.Overview,&tag.Genre_ids)
             if err != nil {
             fmt.Println(err)
            }
            fmt.Println(tag.Id)
            list.Results = append(list.Results,tag)
         }

        err = rows.Err()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }

        defer db.Close()


            //fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q\n", list.Results[3])
            w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(list) 
            //spew.Dump(list)
            //fmt.Fprintf(w, "given lamguage, %q\n", tag.Poster_path)



}

func main() {
    handleRequests()

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.FileServer()` should not be called in a function like that. It returns a `Handler function` (a function similar to the `posterfunc` you created).

It should be used as the handler function in the route configuration like this:

```
myRouter.HandleFunc("/poster_path/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("./your_dir")))
```

Here you can find the [documentation for `http.FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer), with some more detailed examples.

[This blog post](https://lets-go.alexedwards.net/sample/02.09-serving-static-files.html) does a fine step-by-step explanation on how to set it up.

UPDATE:

If you want to use it inside your handler, you should use `http.ServeFile`. It will respond to the request with the contents of the named file or directory.

[Docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile)

```
func posterfunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    key := vars["id"]
    var url = "/home/rakshithjk/Desktop/poster/"+key+".jpg"
    http.ServeFile(w, r, url)
}
```

UPDATE 2:

The issue in the new snippet is that you are printing to the interface just before serving the file.
Remove this line:

```
fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q\n", url)
```

Comment: But the problem with using the above method is that my file location varies depending on the parameter value in the url. How do i incorporate that ?

Comment: I see. I'm updating my response

Comment: I went through the blog post, it was mentioned that `http.ServeFile` is used to serve files within handler function. Tried incorporating that, but still did'nt work

Comment: I updated my response. Can you try it out ? 
I'll create a simple project here to test it as well.

Comment: i did, but the image is still not shown as output. It's still showing the same output in postman as mentioned in the question

Comment: I'm not sure postman can render images. You can try the same url in your browser window. 
It worked here.

Comment: The other possible issue could be your program not having access to the folder you pointed it to. Test it with a image inside your project's folder !

Comment: Postman can render images, and i also tried testing it on browser with different image locations, but still didn't work. I'm baffled

Comment: I have it like this `var url = "./" + key + ".png"`. It worked fine with an image in the same folder as the main file. Are you sure the image you requested exists ?

Comment: tried everything, still doesn't work. I've updated my entire code above, kindly help debug this error